# Why my HTML horizontal scroll won't work?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I tried using these css code

```
.graph3{
    background-color:#B88E8E;
    width 950px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

and this HTML code

```
<div class="graph3">
        <h3>房价与楼龄的散步图</h3>
        <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <li style="display: inline"><img src="AP/yizhuangkaifaquAP.png" title ="亦庄开发区房价域面积" width="290" height ="220"></li>
        <li style="display: inline"><img src="AP/yizhuangkaifaquAP.png" title ="亦庄开发区房价域面积" width="290" height ="220"></li>
        <li style="display: inline"><img src="AP/yizhuangkaifaquAP.png" title ="亦庄开发区房价域面积" width="290" height ="220"></li>
        <li style="display: inline"><img src="AP/yizhuangkaifaquAP.png" title ="亦庄开发区房价域面积" width="290" height ="220"></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
```

But they still won't use the horizontal scroll and used vertical scroll instead.
[This is the picture of the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc9Cg.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You add `white-space: nowrap;` to your container so your problem will be solved
Just update your CSS with the following code

```
.graph3 {
    background-color: #B88E8E;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 950px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```